# How to make git ignore changes to submodules by default

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, git-config

Since gitmodules were introduced in Git, I like to add them like so:

```
[submodule "actionbarsherlock"]
path = actionbarsherlock
url = git://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock.git
ignore = dirty
```

The important part here is `ignore = dirty`.

When using the `git submodule add` command, I'm forced to add this line by myself in the `.gitmodules` file.

How can I make this the default behavior for every `git submodule add` I'll make in the futur?

I know about the `submodule.<name>.ignore` configuration, but how to apply it to all by default?

Comment: Don't know if there's a way to do this by default, but you could easily add an alias or script to do it for you.

Comment: I don't see how to do that by alias. And as for script, I just hoped git had a default option for it

Comment: Git will treat as an alias any script in $PATH that starts with `git-<command>` as `git <command>`. You could just write a shell script that accepts the submodules name, adds it, then issues the `submodule.<name>.ignore` configuration and just call it `git supersubmodule` or something.

Comment: @Christopher I know I can do that, so they really are no git options for it? Please post an answer with your last comment if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to close this, **no**, there is not default option for it (sadly).

Comment: This still appears to be true on git v2.7.0.

Answer (score 7):

2014: Note that even if there were such a config, git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014) would still show you a submodule which has been staged.

See [commit 1d2f393](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d2f393ac9bfb4c20f14d6ead7bb4c56e766ab77) by [Jens Lehmann (`jlehmann`)](https://github.com/jlehmann)

> Currently setting `submodule.<name>.ignore` and/or `diff.ignoreSubmodules` to "`all`" suppresses all output of submodule changes for the diff family, status and commit.
>
> **For status and commit this is really confusing, as it even when the user chooses to record a new commit for an ignored submodule by adding it manually this change won't show up under the to-be-committed changes.
>
> To add insult to injury, a later "git commit" will error out with "`nothing to commit`" when only ignored submodules are staged.**
>
> Fix that by making `wt_status` always print staged submodule changes, no matter what ignore settings are configured.
> The only exception is when the user explicitly uses the "`--ignore-submodules=all`" command line option, in that case the submodule output is still suppressed.
> This also makes "`git commit`" work again when only modifications of ignored submodules are staged, as that command uses the "commitable" member of the `wt_status` struct to determine if staged changes are present.

See also [commit c215d3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c215d3d2826c882feb819e5743287ec74d9ff693) for the `git commit` part.

---

> To add insult to injury, a later "git commit" will error out with "nothing to commit" when only ignored submodules are staged.

Actually... with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), even when `diff.ignoreSubmodules` tells us to ignore submodule changes, "[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4ee088deb83e2a4a78ac3882168b3e8fadd4f541/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> with an index that already records changes to submodules should include the submodule changes in the resulting commit, but it did not.
And this has been fixed!

See [commit 5768478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5768478edc2bccb6a3d6200e430490573140bfa6) (14 Jun 2023) by [Josip Sokcevic (`sokac`)](https://github.com/sokac).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ee088d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ee088deb83e2a4a78ac3882168b3e8fadd4f541), 23 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff-lib`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5768478edc2bccb6a3d6200e430490573140bfa6): honor `override_submodule_config` flag bit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josip Sokcevic</sup>

> When `diff.ignoreSubmodules = all` is set and submodule commits are manually staged (e.g. via `git-update-index`), `git-commit` should record the commit  with updated submodules.
>
> `index_differs_from` is called from `prepare_to_commit` with flags set to `override_submodule_config = 1`.
> `index_differs_from` then merges the default diff flags and passed flags.
>
> When `diff.ignoreSubmodules` is set to "`all`", `flags` ends up having both `override_submodule_config` and `ignore_submodules` set to 1. This results in `git-commit` ignoring staged commits.
>
> This patch restores original `flags.ignore_submodule` if `flags.override_submodule_config` is set.

Comment: Same deal for git-gui: https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0db1dd7d4bc87825f0d7d743f1a01b4461a59ff

Answer (score 3):

Today I found out that can use `git config` to change the `.gitmodules` file, and therefore can add the ignore dirty flag without going into the file and adding the line by hand:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.actionbarsherlock.ignore dirty
```

In my case, I was able to automate the two steps in a script with that command.

Answer (score 2):

```
[submodule "book"]
    path = book
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    ignore = all
```

or use

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.tests.ignore all
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a default option. Were it a binary state (ignore or not), you could get traction with:

```
diff.ignoreSubmodules
   Sets the default value of --ignore-submodules. Note that this affects only git diff Porcelain, and not lower level diff commands such as git diff-files.  git checkout also
   honors this setting when reporting uncommitted changes.
```

But as you're using `dirty` I'm not sure there's a way to set a default. Regardless, you could do this with a git alias in your `$PATH`. Write a script that accepts the submodule as an argument and set the proper `dirty` configuration value, then add that script to your `$PATH`. Call it `git-<command>` and it'll be available as `git <command>`.

Comment: Ok, I know options for diff and status, but would like a better thing. A script is a posible option.

Comment: This is a good candidate for the git list. THey could give you a definite answer, and if that answer is "no", a patch might be proposed.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

`git config --global core.ignore dirty`

which writes the preference to your `~/.gitconfig` file.

Comment: I don't think it works. At least it's not working for me (git 1.8.5).

Comment: @brianclements What version supports this option?

Comment: I use git 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. But on second revisit, I think this doesn't work for me either. But then again, alerting me to "new commits" and "untracked content" for my submodules is the behavior I wanted anyway perhaps I misunderstood OP's question.